# Converting propositional logic argument to Prolog

Tags: syntax, prolog, logic, predicate, proof

How do I translate the following argument into Prolog? It seems like it doesn't need predicates. (Note: I use & for a conjunction and | for a disjunction.)

> G -> (H & J)
>
> (H | J) -> S
>
> S | R
>
> Ⱶ G -> R

Also, how would I consult the Prolog database to determine that (G -> R) is false and the argument is therefore invalid? It has been a while.

(Yes, this is for homework. The professor asked us to prove the argument, but it is not valid if G, H, J, and S are true and R is false.)

*Edit:*

Based on Daniel's answer, I've written this:

```
boolean(true).
boolean(fail).
argument(G, H, J, R, S) :-
    boolean(G),
    boolean(H),
    boolean(J),
    boolean(R),
    boolean(S),
    (G -> R) ->
    (G -> (H , J)),
    ((H ; J) -> S),
    (S ; R).
```

But when I run it, I get this:

```
?- argument(G, H, J, R, S).
G = H, H = J, J = R, R = S, S = true.
```

How can I get it to show the fail case?

*Edit #2:*

Now I have this:

```
boolean(true).
boolean(false).
argument(G, H, J, R, S) :-
    boolean(G), boolean(H), boolean(J), boolean(R), boolean(S),
    (((G -> R); true) ->
    ((G -> (H , J); true),
    ((H ; J) -> S; true),
    (S ; R))); true.
```

It goes through all the successful cases, like you would expect Prolog to do, but I really want it to also show when the argument is invalid, i.e. when the predicate fails. I don't know how to do this.

Comment: The easiest thing I can think of to get the failure cases is to pull out the `boolean(G), ...` line into a separate predicate, then `write/1` their values out before entering `argument/5`, and then write yes or no depending on whether it succeeds. You could also at that point say `\+ argument(...` which negates the call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Prolog, conjunction is `,` and disjunction is `;`. Implication is still just `->` but the precedence isn't always intuitive so we tend to wrap implied cases in parentheses. So your first three cases are just:

```
G -> (H, J).
(H ; J) -> S.
S ; R.
```

I'm not sure what Ⱶ adds here, but if I were guessing I'd be inclined to translate this argument as:

```
(G -> R) :-
  G -> (H, J),
  (H ; J) -> S,
  (S ; R).
```

Since these are all Prolog variables this won't execute though. Prolog will need to be told what domains `H`, `J` and `S` belong to, at the very least.

Comment: Ⱶ is supposed to be turnstile, i.e. "therefore." Or in other words, the three arguments imply the conclusion. Would the final part of your code be correct for that? (I'm just not sure, I don't really know :P)

Comment: Also, if I understand correctly, atoms can be enclosed in single quotes, so 'G' is an atom for example.

Comment: I found that the `->` operator doesn't mean the same thing as implication in logic. `A -> B` is only true in Prolog if both `A` and `B` are true. Apparently, the `->` operator only evaluates the right hand term if the left hand term is true.

Comment: By making the conclusion the head, we're telling Prolog that to prove it, it must prove the three steps first. The code isn't really meaningful with the "variables" as Prolog variables or atoms; in both cases, Prolog will "prove" them trivially.

Comment: You can change `A -> B` to `A -> B ; true` to get the behavior you want from Prolog's implication.

Comment: Awesome. By the way, with the way you wrote that argument, I get the "No permission to modify static_procedure" error. What's the best way to get around this?

Comment: Name your predicate something other than `G -> R`. This is sketch code. If you want to make something really executable this is just one of many things you'd have to change.